# Remove database in a Rails project and all and all associated files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently building an application in Rails that consumes an API, recently I had to to generate a model and save some records to "solve" some problems, but I don't have that problem now and so I would like to ask.

1. In my case (using an API), it is good practice not to use a database at all?
2. If the answer above is yes, what files can I delete my project to leave my Rails project as clean as possible? (out of things you will use)

Comment: PS. Don't use both the ruby-on-rails-3 and ruby-on-rails-4 tags. They are used to indicate that the question is specifically about 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

***In my case (using an API), it is good practice not to use a database at all?***

Most kinds of applications require some sort of long term storage - I would say the cases where it is not needed are more of an exception - so no you cannot generally say that not using a database is a good practice.

Even if you are using an external API as the persistence layer you will still want to have models in your application as the holders of your business logic. Models in rails are not just storage - they also build up the actual domain and set up rules and relations for the objects in it.

In Rails ActiveModel and the default ORM ActiveRecord are separate entities - ActiveModel works fine without AR.

```
# A rails model without ActiveRecord
class Pet
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Plus you might want to use some sort of persistence such as memcached or redis for performance and to reduce the amount of API requests.

***If the answer above is yes, what files can I delete my project to leave my Rails project as clean as possible?***

You can generate a rails app without ActiveRecord with the `--skip-active-record` option, `rails new someapp -O`. To remove the ActiveRecord from an existing app you would remove the related gems from the Gemfile and the middleware from `config/application.rb`.